# How can you check if a user has a particular role in a particular server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, patreon

I want to make Patreon Only commands for my bot, but I don't know how I can make it so I can restrict access to a command based on 1 role in 1 server, I want the command to work globally, but I want the people on the "Patreon" role on my support server to have only access to the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.utils.get) to get the Patreon role, then iterate through the member's roles and a simple `if-else`.

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    homeGuild = client.get_guild(7300646418576xxxxx)  # Home Guild/Support Server; where user has "Patreon" role.
    patreonRole = get(homeGuild.roles, id=7570088168301xxxxx)  # Patreon role ID that a user must have.
    member = []

    for pledger in homeGuild.members:
        if pledger == ctx.author:
            member = pledger

    if patreonRole in member.roles:
        await ctx.send("You are a Patreon.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("You are not a Patreon.")
```

Comment: im guessing the ID you put there is a role id, right?

Comment: Yes, it's commented in the code.

Comment: it only works in the support server (where the role is from) and not anywhere else, is there any way i could fix that?

Comment: Sure, check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

In your command, use [get_guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_guild#discord.Client.get_guild) to get your support server guild, then [Guild.get_member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_member#discord.Guild.get_member) to get the member object of whoever is executing the command (ctx.author.id).  You can then check if your `Patreon` role is in that member's [Member.roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=roles#discord.Member.roles) (I would use [utils.get](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=utils%20get#discord.utils.get)) and exit the command if not.

Comment: lol epic the other guy edited in my solution very cool